# What's the proper way to replace a UIViewController with a UITableController without a navigation controller stack?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Assuming I start with a blank project, and I add 2 views (UIViewController,UITableController).

What's the proper way to jump from a UIViewController to a UITableController without a navigation controller stack?

**Ex: think of a welcome page, click here to continue, and it takes you to the table controller.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If these are the ONLY view controllers, you can do it by reassigning the `rootViewController` property of the `UIWindow` Just set it to whichever controller you want to display, and it will do the rest.

Comment: What do you mean "if these are ONLY view controllers? btw I think UIWindow rootViewController might be what I need in my case (Dispose view and move to a table controller).

Comment: I meant that rootViewController is shown full screen. So if you were doing something weird, this isn't' what you want. Sounds like it should do what you need though.

Comment: Just another idea: you can also set the rootViewController of UIWindow to UITableViewController and present the UIViewController modally, (presentModalViewController), and then dismiss it. It will look much like the Google+ app for iPhone (the sign-in page).

Answer (score 0):

I would not have 2 view controllers then in that case if it's a welcome page type of thing. I would have a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` in its view and a view over the top of the table view at the start which when you tap a button, gets hidden - i.e. just 1 view controller.

Comment: if the 1 view controller is the UITableViewController... then what the "view over the top" be? How can I make this work with "just 1 view controller"?

Comment: Edited to be a bit clearly. Sorry I meant a `UIViewController` which had a table view on it, and a view over that. Does that make sense?

Comment: oh ok, yes. Your technique does make sense. However, my question is more about understanding how to discard a view, and display a table view. I'm new to IOS so and I'm trying to understand the best or proper way to discard a view and display another. Thanks for your help! Any other pointers?